# .Net Core + MongoDb Create Database Automatically according to entities

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have been working on a .Net Core project and I want to use MongoDb as a database implementation. I have created my entities that will be created as Collections. You can see the entities below.

When I start the project and if the database does not exist on the server, database and collections must be created according to entities that I have created. I should not create a database manually.

For Mssql, I am using FluentMigrator for this process. How can I handle it for MongoDb?

```
/// <summary>
/// BaseEntity abstract class implementations
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseEntity : IEntity<string>
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement(Order = 0)]
    public string Id { get; } = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.DateTime)]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Utc)]
    [BsonElement(Order = 101)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}


public class Basket : BaseEntity
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should not create a database manually

I think we have some miss-understood here, on `IMongoClient` interface, it has a method `GetDatabase` that will create the database automatically on the server if it doesn't exists yet, so... basically, that kind of migration is automatic.

> database and collections must be created according to entities that I have created

`IMongoDatabase` interface have `GetCollection<YourEntityType>(Your collection name)` that would generate the collection too as far as I can remember.(My code got fully worked, despite I'm not setting anything on the database).

I think our most realistic case was create the index on the collection if it's doesn't exists yet.